# Create Array Beginning at Specific Address

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

In C++, is it possible to create an array of a specific size (such as short array[2048]) which begins at a specific address, such as 0x1000?

Comment: How do know the specific address? Is it something fixed? Or something like this : `void *address = malloc(size);`?

Comment: It's given. For example, 0x1000.

Comment: There isn't a standard way to do this.  Your platform/compiler may offer a non-standard mechanism to do this, though.  If you edit your question to include details of your platform, you may get a better answer ;)

Comment: It may improve answers to describe what you want to achieve.  Why is the particular memory address important to you?

Comment: @JohnRoberts: *"It's given"*, is not an answer to the question in my comment. I'm asking about the nature of specific address? Where do you get it from?

Comment: @Nawaz I would be hard coding it in.

Comment: @John Roberts: What Nawaz is asking for is the significance of the memory address you wish to put your array at. Is it something required by the hardware you're working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.
In **non-embedded systems** (for which I'll limit my answer to) the user address space is a **virtual address space**. Meaning that even if you get a pointer which points to 0x1000 that is **not the physical location** of your allocated data in the physical memory map. So, since the system hides physical addresses from you - you can't request a specific **physical** address. Virtual addresses however, are adiffernet story...

Having understood that there is no guarantee that pointing to 0x1000 will actually mean that you are pointing to the **physical address** 0x1000, in Linux you can use the function `mmap()` and its Windows counterpart `VirtualAlloc()` to request allocation to a specific **virtual** address. Of course these functions are not guaranteed to work (for instance, if the virtual address you are requesting is already mapped or if it is system "reserved").

Answer (score 2):

In an embedded system you could use the linker file to map a symbol or special segment there. Or possibly a pragma. This is a pretty common thing for embedded systems where a bootloader needs a shared memory space with the app it starts, or a coprocessor has a shared memory bank with the main CPU at a fixed address. The problem is that the method varies from tool to tool.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using placement new:

```
struct A { short array[2048]; };
char *addr = (char*)0x1000;
new (addr) A;
```

If you want dynamic size, use the following:

```
new (addr) short[size];
```

Comment: doesn't placement new work only if the address has been allocated before?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an embedded systems, your question does make sense <strike>at all</strike>.

Usually you would access memory mapped registers of peripherals by defining a volatile pointer with a size of the register. However as this approach is common it has a downside as soon as coding standards like MISRA or CERT C are involved. These standards claim that pointers are a dangerous thing within a safety critical system in general. So you should avoid them wherever possible.

As I stumble over this issue for a while, there seems to be "better" approaches available like this one ([Mapping variables to specific addresses](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3750.html)) stated by ARM. You have to define a structure/array in a own compilation unit (result of this is a single .o-file). After this you need to write a linker-file that places this single .o-file at the specified address.

Comment: "your question does make sense at all" <-- Either a "not" is missing, or there is an extraneous "at all"... Not to be facetious, but right now this statement does not make sense.

Answer (score -1):

If you want an array just like that at a specific address you could put it in a struct of which you can then assign a pointer pointing to the desired location. See this example:

```
struct A {
  short array[2048];
};

int main(char argc, char** argv) {
  A* a = (A*)0x1000;
  printf("%p\n", &a->array[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't "create" (allocate) the array. It just reads the contents in address 0x1000. This is not what the OP requested.

Comment: I do not agree with your interpretation of OP's intentions.

Comment: @eladidan: I can't completely agree with your comment. In embedded systems like microcontrollers, you access things like input/output pins and special function registers in a manner just like this, where you dereference hard-coded pointers. At best, the OP intentions are unclear.

Comment: That is true, though I doubt (personal interpretation) that he was talking about embedded systems without specifying it or tagging it.